# Почему при клике на текст в консоль не выводится строка 'd'?

Tags: javascript

```js
let Ad2 = document.querySelectorAll('.d');
for (i = 0; i < Ad2.length; i++) {
  Ad2[i].onclick = () => {
    console.log('d');
  };
}
```

```html
<p class="d">test-1</p>
<p class="d">test-2</p>
<p class="d">test-3</p>
```

Comment: Эмм... выводится. Ну разве что в строгом режиме будет ошибка - переменная 'i' не объявлена. Поэтому хорошо бы писать `for( let i = 0; ...`

Comment: сдается мне, что скрипт выполняется до построения DOM. Надо бы обернуть в `DOMContentLoaded`

Comment: Все выводится. Но лучше делать через addEventListener